# onclick help - reading the value of a specific class

Tags: jquery

I hope my description will not be too confusing! I am trying to integrate a javascript shopping cart, simplecart-js, into a Jquery LightBox, Yoxview. Yoxview has an option to add button links in the popup title pane for various options, downloading, shopping cart, etc. The relevant code for the shopping cart button is:

```
var yoxviewCartButton = $("<a>", {
    title: "Add to cart",
            href: "javascript:;",
    onclick:"simpleCart.add('name=Awesome', 'price=14.95','quantity=1');"
        });
        yoxviewCartButton.append($("<img>", {
            src: "yoxview/images/yoxview_cart_icon.png",
            alt: "Add to cart",
            css: { width: 18, height: 18 },

        }));
```

the specific integration for shopingcart-js into the button is:

```
href: "javascript:;",
onclick:"simpleCart.add('name=Awesome', 'price=14.95','quantity=1');
```

the html structure I'm using is:

```
<a class="item yoxview simpleCart_shelfItem" href="pics/pic0.png" title="Test1">
<img class="content" src="pics/pic0.png" title="Test1"/>
<span class="caption item_name">Pic 0 
<span class="item_price">$14.99</span></span></a>
```

The onclick event works but inputs the same info for each image, obviously, so I am trying to get the "item_name" and "item_price" for each "simpleCart_shelfItem" to input into the name= and price= field of the onclick event. I'm not sure how to get jquery to input these values. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

BTW, Before I tried butchering this code, the original code was set to show an alert:

```
 var yoxviewCartButton = $("<a>", {
            title: "Add to cart",
            href: "#",
            click: function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("The image \"" + $(this).data("yoxview_cart") + "\" can be added to cart through AJAX.");
            }
        });
        yoxviewCartButton.append($("<img>", {
            src: "../images/yoxview_cart_icon.png",
            alt: "Add to cart",
            css: { width: 18, height: 18 }
        }));

        $(".yoxview").yoxview({ 
            infoButtons: {
                download: yoxviewDownloadButton,
                cart: yoxviewCartButton
            },
            onSelect: function(i, image)
            {
                $.yoxview.infoButtons.download.attr("href", image.media.src);
                $.yoxview.infoButtons.cart.data("yoxview_cart", image.media.src);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yoxview requires that you pass in strings for `href` and `onclick`? Presumably to be `eval`ed later? Yuck.

Comment: I'm not sure it's required and I could integrate the cart into the image title but a button in the popup is a bit nicer. The original code for the button was:href: "#",
                click: function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("The image \"" + $(this).data("yoxview_cart") + "\" can be added to cart through AJAX.");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set `onclick` as an attribute from a string. It's ugly and won't work in IE. Use jQuery's own event handling methods like `click()`.

Also, don't use a link for something that isn't a link (especially with a `javascript:` URL; avoid). You don't want to give the user link affordances like open-in-new-window that simply aren't present. Use a button, and if you don't want it to look like a button you can use CSS to remove background, borders etc.

```
$('.simpleCart_shelfItem').each(function() {
    var name= $(this).children('span')[0].firstChild.data;
    var price= $(this).find('span>span').text().replace('$', '');
    var button= $('<button/>', {type: 'button', 'class': 'looksUnlikeAButton'});
    button.append($('<img/>', {src: 'yoxview/images/yoxview_cart_icon.png', title: 'Add to cart', width: 18, height: 18});
    button.click(function() {
        simpleCart.add('name='+name, 'price='+price, 'quantity=1');
    });
    $('#whereeverYouWantToPutIt').append(button);
});
```

(this uses plain DOM `firstChild.data` to pick off the initial text in the outer `<span>`. Normally you would use `text()`, but that would return the price in the nested span as well. It would be easier if they were two separate spans, you could just `text()` on each one.)

Comment: Two separate spans is a much better idea. I must admit my ignorance in where I should insert this code in relation to the yoxviewCartButton varialble. I Keep getting errors or the buttons disappear when I try to implement it.